# I am wanting to integrate a core .Net based web application with my test suite using Azure Pipelines and just wanted to know the possibilites

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, katalon-studio, smoke-testing

I am working as a QA Lead in a product based company. I have developed a **"Smoke Test Automation Suite"** using **Katalon Studio** for a **"core .Net based web application"**.
Now i am planning to integrate my Smoke Test Automation Suite with the core .Net based web application using **Azure Pipelines** over the **cloud**. Which means post integration over the cloud if any commit is performed on the "core .Net based web application" project my "Smoke Test Automation Suite" which too resides on cloud should run automatically and publish the smoke test results. We are currently using **Azure Devops** and **Azure Pipelines** is a sub entity of it.

i have tried creating a sample pipeline but completely failed to integrate the "Smoke Test Automation Suite" with the "core .Net based web application" on cloud. I am looking for some one who can help me with this and kindly please do let me know if i had to provide with some more information.

Many thanks in advance.w

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the [dotnet core yaml pipeline example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops) in Microsoft sites. If you have followed the example and still failed to run the tests. You are most likely specify the path of the smoke test project wrongly. And your pipeline tasks failed to find the test project.

For classic view pipeline. You can follow below steps

In your project go to **Pipelines**-->select **New** to create a new pipeline --> select **Use the classic editor**--> configure your azure repo--> choose a template (you can choose **ASP.NET CORE** template or ASP.NET CORE(.NET Framework))

[image]

Then you need to configure the **path to project** and check **publish test results**

[image]

To enable Continuous integration. you need to go to the trigger tab and check **Enable continuous integration** (By enabling CI, the pipeline will be triggered when you commit a change to your repo)

[image]

You will need the [pre-defined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to refer to project files.

If you still cannot get your smoke test run. Please share the definition of your pipeline and also the error message of the failed tasks.